# what is the error in the below code ? how to solve the error

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dataset=pd.read_csv('iris.csv')
dataset.shape
dataset.head(10)
feature_column = ['sepal_length','sepal_width','petal_length','petal_width']
x=dataset[feature_column].values
=dataset['species'].values
dataset[feature_column].values
dataset['species'].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le=LabelEncoder()
y=le.fit_transform(y)
y[:10]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, y_train,X_test, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-65776283812c> in <module>
      1 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
----> 2 X_train, y_train,X_test, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

NameError: name 'X' is not defined
```

Comment: is it something silly like capitalization at your data declaration x=dataset[feature_column].values

Comment: I started editing the post but it's all over the place. Just copy/paste your code from the script and use crtl + k, or click the `{}` button in the editor

Comment: Its a Capitalization issue, you created the data for 'x' and then trying to split the data of 'X'. You either rename your 'x' to 'X' or 'X' to 'x'.

Comment: Flagging it due to simple typographical error.

Answer (score 2):

The error is very specific... It comes from this line:

```
X_train, y_train,X_test, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
```

You pass `X` (uppercase) as first parameter to the `train_test_split()`
function but it's not defined before. I believe you meant to pass `x` (lowercase) instead.

PS: Please note that according to PEP8, uppercase names should only be used for constants: [PEP8 constants](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have never defined `X`, you did define `x`. Remember python does difference capitalization.
Therefore you should try and redefine `x` as `X` or, pass `x` to your function.

```
X_train, y_train,X_test, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
```

Otherwise:

```
X=dataset[feature_column].values
X_train, y_train,X_test, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
```